# What companies offer through bus tickets from Mexico City to Los Angeles?

Tags: tickets, buses, los-angeles, mexico-city

I've been searcing for ways to get from Mexico City to Los Angeles by bus, and so far the only thing I've found is Greyhound, which, combined with partner companies, takes you to LA with changes in Chihuahua, Tijuana and San Ysidro for USD 235 (which cannot be bought online)

Are there any other companies offering through tickets between Mexico City and Los Angeles (possibly with interchanges)?

(no, I am not interested in taking the plane)

Comment: Seriously :-) it's nearly 3000 km; have you considered cheapo flight to Tijuana and then the bus from San Ysidro to LA? You'd then enter at the land crossing which may take care of the concerns in your other question. Also, there are independent companies which serve Mexicans and run non-stop to cities in the US. Locals might know.

Comment: @Dorothy Got nothing to do with that. I simply wish to experience the trip through rural Mexico, and am probably going to both places anyway

Comment: Aha, I understand; SAFE journey.

Comment: @Dorothy Is intercity bus travel in Mexico unsafe?

Comment: Anecdotally, yes. Review [this, especially for areas through which you'd travel](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/alertswarnings/mexico-travel-warning.html) I'm still looking for independent companies that run the route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long-haul buses between major Mexican and US cities are [feeling the pinch of the ULCC airlines like Volaris](http://www.chicagobusiness.com/article/20160618/ISSUE01/306189992/the-hottest-destination-from-midway-isnt-in-the-u-s), I'm not sure if there are any direct lines at the moment.

Alternatively you could ride from DF over to Guadalajara on [Primera Plus](https://www.primeraplus.com.mx/), [Elite](https://www.autobuseselite.com.mx) or some other line. From Guadalajara there there are several companies that go straight up to LA:

- [TAP Royal](http://taproyal.com/)'s route map shows that they offer service in DF but I only found schedules starting in Guadalajara to LA in their search box.
- [Tufesa](http://www.tufesa.com.mx/) runs two trips a day.
- [ACN](https://www.acnautobuses.com/)

Otherwise there are various bus lines to both DF and LA from other places in Central Mexico like Durango.